# Prove that the Set $P$ of algebraic polynomial is a first category set in $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, baire-category, the-baire-space

Prove that the set $P$ of algebraic polynomial is a first category set in $C[a, b]$
I know the definition of first category is countable union of nowhere dense sets. and further more I know that the set of algebraic numbers is countable. and set of polynomials is dense in in $C[a, b]$. Now How can I use all these known facts here to prove my problem

Comment: $C[a,b]$ is all continuous maps from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$ right?

Comment: I am also stuggling the same problem,do you have some idea @ Jake

Answer (score 1):

Since P is the countable union of $P_n$, the set of polynomials of degree at most n, it suffices to show each $P_n$ is nowhere dense. Since $P_n$ is closed it suffices to show that its interior is empty. Take a polynomial $p \in P_n$. Then take a polynomial $q \in P_{n+1}$ whose first coefficients all agree with the coefficients of $q$. Then the sup norm of the difference between the two polynomials is $\lVert a_{n+1}x^{n+1}\rVert$ which can be made as small as desired by taking $a_{n+1}$ small enough. So for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $p\in P_n$ there exists a function not in $P_n$ that is contained in $B_{\epsilon}(p)$ so there are no open balls of elements of $P_n$ that are contained in $P_n$, so the interior of $P_n$ is empty and hence $P_n$ is nowhere dense, as desired.